# What happens to println() when object is passed

Tags: java

```
Circle c = new Circle(colour, radius);
System.out.println(c);
```

Consider a class `Circle` now what will the `println` statement do when we have `toString()` method in class `Circle` and when we do not have one.

Comment: You always have `toString()` in Java objects. If the class didn't declare its own, `toString` will come from superclasses or from `Object` if no intermediate superclass provides it.

Comment: Too bad the source code of `println` cannot be read somewhere. And too bad there is absolutely no way to execute a program step-by-step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toString()` is a method of `Object` class and this class is superclass of all classes (if you create a new class, that extends no other class, it will implicitly inherit from `Object` class. Remember that Java does not support multiple inheritance i.e class can have only one **direct** superclass). If you override `toString()` in inheriting class then your implemnentation will be called by `System.out.println()` implicitly. If you do not override this method, also `toString()` will be invoked but with default implementation from `Object` class. And the default implementation of [`Object::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) returns :

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>   getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())